# Dynamically add image to django page via javascript?

Tags: javascript, django, mapbox

I'm trying to add an image to a django page via Mapbox's API, which has the following syntax:

```
    new mapboxgl.Popup()
        .setLngLat(features[0].geometry.coordinates)
        .setHTML(" <img src=\"../images/location_icon.png\" />")
        .addTo(map);
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. I assume that because we're skirting around the whole idea of templates (by dynamically adding the image), I don't need to use {% %} , but I'm not entirely sure about that.

I've tried this as well, but to no avail:

```
.setHTML(" <img src='{%\"images/location_icon.png\"%}' />")
```

Does anybody know what the proper syntax is for accomplishing this?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a useless problem description. We already know that :) Are you getting any errors in the console? So far, Django is completely unrelated to this issue, and you'd only need template syntax like `{% %}` if you were inserting backend data into your HTML/JS.

Comment: No, I'm not getting errors in the console. Obviously I would have mentioned that if I had been. I'm simply getting a broken image icon appended, and beyond that I have no idea what's happening.

Comment: In that case it's most likely a path issue, meaning that from the document's location, the image isn't at `../images/location_icon.png`

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to use AJAX. You'll leave the html element that holds the picture empty until AJAX gets a response, it'll contain the image's path, and then you use JavaScript to render that image in its place.

Read up on AJAX, because I'm not actually sure I understood your question correctly.